# Kubernetes Cron Jobs - Run multiple pods for a cron job

Tags: kubernetes

Our requirement is we need to do batch processing every 3 hours but single process can not handle the work load. we have to run multiple pods for the same cron job. Is there any way to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `single process can not handle the work load`. Do you mean to say that the batch process huge data or does huge computation and the processing/computation can be parallelised with multiple batch process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide `parallelism: <num_of_pods>` to `cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec` and it will run the multiple pods () at the same time.

Following is the example of a cronjob which runs 3 nginx pod every minute.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: cron1
  name: cron1
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      parallelism: 3
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            run: cron1
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: nginx
            name: cron1
            resources: {}
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
status: {}
```

Comment: But in my case there is one more condition. So let us say we scheduled a job to run every 3 hours. it ran at 8a.m. if any of the container is still running at 11a.m. basically if the job is not finished yet we don't want it to trigger again. To make this possible we need to make concurrencyPolicy: forbid.

Comment: Yes, `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid`  forbids concurrent runs, skipping next run if the previous run hasn't finished yet